# how to get vocabulary id from node id in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I need to know how can i get vocabulary id from the node id in page.tpl.php in drupal 7.

I have this structure in my drupal.

e.g. There is two Content types

1. Content1
2. Content2
3. Content1 have Vocabulary named "vocab1" and "vocab2".
4. Now "Vocab1" have terms "term1" and "term2".
5. and "Vocab2" have terms "term3" and "term4".

Similarly

1. Content2 have Vocabulary named "vocab3" and "vocab4".
2. Now "Vocab3" have terms "term5" and "term6".
3. and "Vocab4" have terms "term7" and "term8".

Now I am adding the node using the content type "Content2" with selecting the "term7". Now I am try to get that vocabulary id on page.tpl.php but i didn't found any solution.

I searched and I didn't found any solution.

There is one solution

i.e.

`$field = $node->field_my_vocabulary;
$terms_en = $field['en'];`

But for getting this way i need to put manually The field "field_my_vocabulary". But the "field_my_vocabulary" can be different for every node as the associated vocabulary will be different. and i want this dynamically.

There is a function available in drupal 6 i.e. taxonomy_node_get_terms() for returning all terms associated with the node id but this function not available in drupal 7.

Please help.

Thanks,
Sunil.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 ways how you can get them in `page.tpl.php`:

- you can get `nid` from url with [arg](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function,

example:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $node = node_load(arg(1)); // we get the node object
  //dpm($node);

  // standart way
  $nodeTermTid = $node->field_MY_TERM_FIELD['und'][0]['tid'];
  $nodeTerm = taxonomy_term_load($nodeTermTid);

  // with entity_metadata_wrapper function (from Entity API)
  $nodeWrapper = entity_metada_wrapper('node', $node);
  $nodeTerm = $nodeWrapper->field_MY_TERM_FIELD->value();

  $vocabularyId = $nodeTerm->vid; // if yoy need a vocabulary id
  // or 
  $vocabularyMachineNmae = $nodeTerm->vocabuary_machine_name;
}
```

- you can node object with [menu_get_object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7)

example:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if ($node != null) {
  // standart way
      $nodeTermTid = $node->field_MY_TERM_FIELD['und'][0]['tid'];
      $nodeTerm = taxonomy_term_load($nodeTermTid);

      // with entity_metadata_wrapper function (from Entity API)
      $nodeWrapper = entity_metada_wrapper('node', $node);
      $nodeTerm = $nodeWrapper->field_MY_TERM_FIELD->value();

      $vocabularyId = $nodeTerm->vid; // if yoy need a vocabulary id
      // or 
      $vocabularyMachineNmae = $nodeTerm->vocabuary_machine_name;
}
```